# is there a faster way to copy select vertex position from one side to another

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode, vertices, optimization

Lets say I am making an object with two sides that are symmetrical, lets say over the X-axis, and I need to realign some vertices to match changes I have made on only one side. then I will go to the first vertex, copy the x-coordinate, paste it into the corresponding vertex on the other side, and put a minus on before hitting enter. Then I will do the same for the Y and the Z-axis, except for the minus. Then I will do that for every single vertex that needs changing. This is boring and takes extra time that I feel I shouldn't need to waste.

now my question is this. Is there a faster way to do this? Can I somehow use something like the symmetrize function for Armatures on a mesh? and also bonus question is it possible to do this to only the selected vertices, and not all of them?

Answer (score 0):

select your vertices -> Mesh > Mirror -> interactive mirror

[image]